# How can I decrease the threads while running jMeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I create a test plan when working with jMeter, and I want to create a test plan with 100 concurrency users.

After first page(homepage) I want to decrease 50 users(drop-off and do not access to next page) while 50 another users continue access to another page.

Someone suggested me use Ultimate Thread Group but I think it can't help.

Any idea for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a **Throughput controller** after your home page, and add all the requests you want to be executed with only 50 users into the throughput controller. you have two options :

- **percent executions**: A number from 0-100 that indicates the percentage of times the controller will execute. "50" means the controller will execute during half the iterations through the test plan.
- **Total executions**: For total execution mode, the number indicates the total number of times the controller will execute.

Check [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) from Jmeter user manual for more information.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to shut down half of threads after 1st request you can do it as follows:

1. Add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) after the first request
2. Put the following expression in the "Condition" area:

   ```
   ${__threadNum} % 2 == 0
   ```
3. Add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler as a child of the If Controller and configure it as follows:

   - Target: `Current Thread`
   - Action: `Stop`

Explanation:

- [__threadNum() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) returns current Thread number
- If current thread number is **even** (2, 4, 6, 8, etc.) this thread goes to the Test Action Sampler therefore it is being shut down
- So first sampler will be executed by 100 threads, second (and following samplers) will be executed by 50 threads as only 50 will remain
- Test Action sampler [doesn't generate any results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) so it is fine to useit, it won't appear in the test metrics

Example [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) structure:

[image: JMeter shut down half of threads]

Comment: Thanks for reply and I understood your idea, but what can I do if I want just 30% continue and 70% drop-off